# How to Align the text next to this picture in this slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I bought this slider: [OnebyOne Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/684613), but I have a problem editing it.
As you can see [over here](http://www.donvos.nl/stack) I'm having problems with the alignment.
I want to have the text next to the picture.

Does anybody know how to align it right?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use simple css and add something like `style="position:relative; top:-100px (or whatever works for you);"`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I can only repeat what @vlex wrote – add something like the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
.text3, .text {
  top: -60px;
}
```

Works fine for me. A saner solution would be to wrap the caption without the image in a `div` and position that one.